# Python requests on Linux is outputting Korean opposed to English when using proxies? It works fine on Windows

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

So I need some help here, and was hoping somebody could clear things up. I have a script in Python that uses requests with the Firefox user agent alongside my proxies which are located in South Korea. Now on Windows the script will output in English, however on Linux it outputs in Korean... And before you ask the server's locale language is set to English, nothing is set to Korean. And I installed the ISO directly from the Ubuntu website. What could be going wrong here? I have tried other websites without this user agent and it displays just fine. Here is my user-agent code: `

```
def get_fingerprint(session, proxy):
    r = session.post(API_BASE + "/auth/fingerprint", headers={
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
    }, proxies=proxy)
    try:
        json.loads(r.text)["fingerprint"]
        return json.loads(r.text)["fingerprint"]
    except:
        print(r.text)
        print(r.status_code)
        sys.exit()
```

`
As you can see I also set the language in the user-agent. It works absolutely fine on Windows, however outputs the proxy's language on linux. Makes absolutely no sense to me.
My locale settings:

```
`root@box ~/Test [1]# locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
`
```